# cakephp is querying extra column and I can't figure out why

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm having some trouble getting cakephp to properly query. Cake is trying to find a non-existant column in one of my tables and I can't figure out why. I have two tables involved with this ; votes and posts. Users can vote on a post.

Here are the tables

```
Table votes
post_id |  user_id | vote

table posts
post_id | tite | body | created | modified  | user_id | vote_total
```

When a user votes on a post their vote gets placed in the votes table, and the vote_total is increased/decreased by their vote.

In the index for posts, users can vote on a post through these two links. Right now I have both sent to the same function just to get one working, then I'll finish the other

```
<td><?php echo $this->Html->link('Upvote', array('action' => 'vote', $post['Post']['id']))?>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link('Downvote', array('action' => 'Downvote', $post['Post']['id']));?></td>
```

When I view index.ctp which displays posts, I get the following error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Post.id' in 'field list'
```

Here is the query that it is preforming

```
SQL Query: SELECT `Post`.`post_id`, `Post`.`title`, `Post`.`body`, `Post`.`created`, `Post`.`modified`, `Post`.`user_id`, `Post`.`vote_total`, `Post`.`id` FROM `blog`.`posts` AS `Post` WHERE 1 = 1
```

**So, my problem is that I don't know where the Post.id is being queried from**. I've been searching through my function and the model and I can't figure out what's happening.

Here's the function my postscontroller

```
public function vote($id=null){ 
$this->layout = 'votes_layout';
$this->Post->Votes->recursive = 0;

$this->Post->id = $id;
$user = $this->Auth->User();
$userid = $user['id'];
$conditions = array('votes.id' => $id, 'votes.user_id' => $userid);

$data = $this->Post->Votes->find('all', array('conditions' => $conditions));

if (isset($data) && !empty($data)) {
    echo '<p>User have already give a vote!</p>';
} else {

    if($this->Post->Votes->validates()){

        if ($this->Post->Votes->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'vote'));
        } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }   
}
}
```

This is in my post model

```
 public $hasMany = array(
    'Votes' => array(
        'className'  => 'Vote',
        )
    );
```

So, my question is what am I doing that is causing cake to query post.id? It's not even a column in my table and I can't figure out where the query is coming from.

**edit**

When I remove the hasMany relationship for votes in my Posts model that querying error goes away, but then I have the following error which references every single post field in the table.

```
Undefined index: id
```

Is this not a hasmany relationship? Each post has many votes, but each user only has 1 vote per post.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are following CakePHP conventions and have `id` in all of your tables.

Since you are calling `$this->Post->Vote->recursive = 0`, CakePHP will select all `Post` related with your `Vote`. Since you have a `Post hasMany Vote` relationship, when it selects a vote via `$this->Post->Vote->find()`, it will check the `Vote.post_id` foreign key first.

Then, in order to select the `Post`, it will have to run a query on `Posts` table for something like `Post.id = Vote.post_id`. That's possibly where the `Post.id` is coming from.

What seems strange though is that its calling `Post.post_id` (which naturally doesn't exist, as I assume you wouldn't associate a model with itself). The function that might possibly be calling that might still be the `recursive` call, however it is attempting to fetch *all* posts. I'm unaware of how your application is coded, but tips for you to trace that further would be turning `recursive` to `-1` and see if that is called (don't worry about missing data). If it isn't running that Query after recursive=-1, then try using something more specific like the `Containable` Component (See CakePHP's Book) to fetch your data - it might be helpful.

I'm not sure whether this would help, just popped out of my head when I saw `Post.id` missing. Please let me know if it works (or not) :)

Comment: I changed it to -1 and nothing changed. I checked out the containable info but I don't think anything happened.

Answer (score 0):

Try this thing :

Your post data is not in correct format :

```
$data = array('post_id'=>$id,'user_id'=>$userid);

if ($this->Post->Votes->save($data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'vote'));
    } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The vote could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `id` field in both `posts` and `votes` table.

And in you `posts` table you have `post_id` field, but it is not necessary for you case.

So, remove the `post_id` from `posts` table and check the result.

Comment: I think that has *something* to do with it, but I have a feeling my relationships in the models are off. When I change post_id to just id in both my posts and votes table, cake now queries for votes.post_id. When I have them set to post_id in both tables cake queries for votes.id