# Model association trouble with cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, database-relations

I was having trouble with a voting system that I'm trying to make in cakePHP (found here [cakephp is querying extra column and I can't figure out why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805539/cakephp-is-querying-extra-column-and-i-cant-figure-out-why)) but I figured that out and now I'm having another issue.

I'm making a voting system, and the problem I'm having is that only one user can vote on a given post. For example, if user 1 votes on post 1, and then user 2 votes on post 1, user 2's vote will overwrite user 1's vote.

Here are my tables

```
Votes
id |   user_id   | vote

Posts
id | title | body | created | modified | user_id | vote_total
```

I'm having trouble setting up the associations

1. Users can vote on many posts
2. A post can have many votes, but only 1 per user

This is in my Users model

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Posts' => array( 'className'  => 'Post'),
     'Votes' => array('className'  => 'Vote')
    );
```

This is in my Posts model

```
 public $hasMany = array( //there can be multiple votes of the same id (references post table)
    'Votes' => array('foreignKey' => 'id')
    );
```

I don't have a votes controller. It's done through a vote function on PostsController.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public $hasMany = array( //there can be multiple votes of the same id (references post table)
    'Votes' => array('foreignKey' => 'id')
    );
```

is wrong. It should be:

```
 public $hasMany = array( //there can be multiple votes of the same id (references post table)
'Votes' => array('foreignKey' => 'post_id')
);
```

And so you have to add post_id in the Vote model.

Comment: Did you create it in the database?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that comment after. I changed it, but now a user can vote multiple times on the same post.

Comment: Yes. You now have to add some code in the add method to prevent that.

Comment: I need to add something to the posts method to prevent this? I only have a Posts and Users method. Vote is simply a function in my PostsController

Comment: You have to check in the vote function that it's the first time the user votes.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work. I'm still getting used to cakephp so I'm not sure of all of it's capabilities. Anyway, I appreciate the help.